# Xamarin Round Label Custom renderer not working

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, custom-renderer

I created a custom renderer to create circle behind a label just like badge.

CircleView.cs (PCL)

```
public partial class CircleView : BoxView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(double), typeof(CircleView), 0.0);

        public double CornerRadius
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        public CircleView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

CircleViewRenderer.cs (Android)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CircleView), typeof(CircleViewRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.Droid
{
    public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        private float _cornerRadius;
        private RectF _bounds;
        private Path _path;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var element = (CircleView)Element;

            _cornerRadius = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)element.CornerRadius, Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics);

        }

        protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            if (w != oldw && h != oldh)
            {
                _bounds = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
            }

            _path = new Path();
            _path.Reset();
            _path.AddRoundRect(_bounds, _cornerRadius, _cornerRadius, Path.Direction.Cw);
            _path.Close();
        }

        public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.Save();
            canvas.ClipPath(_path);
            base.Draw(canvas);
            canvas.Restore();
        }
    }
}
```

CircleViewRenderer.cs (iOS)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CircleView), typeof(CircleViewRenderer))]
namespace TestApp.iOS
{
    public class CircleViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Element == null)
                return;

            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
            Layer.CornerRadius = (float)((CircleView)Element).CornerRadius / 2.0f;
        }

    }
}
```

In Xaml i tried like this:

```
<Grid>
<customRenderer:CircleView x:Name="BadgeCircle" HeightRequest="16" WidthRequest="16" CornerRadius="16" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" /><Label x:Name="BadgeLabel" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"/>
</Grid>
```

But its not showing anything. Initializing error was showing on CircleView so i commented InitializeComponent();
What am i missing here?

Comment: Could you please try uncomment the `InitializeComponent()` and build the project?

Comment: its not working and giving error

Comment: Please try clear the project and rebuild it. If there is still error, could you maybe share a basic demo of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a Frame. It should have CornerRadius property.

Otherwise I use this

[XFShapeView](https://github.com/vincentgury/XFShapeView)

this is how you can use it

```
var box = new ShapeView
{
    ShapeType = ShapeType.Box,
    HeightRequest = 75,
    WidthRequest = 75,
    Color = Color.Navy,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    CornerRadius = 5,
    BorderColor = Color.Red,
    BorderWidth = 1f,
    Content = new Label
    {
        Text = "Touch me!",
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof (Label)),
        TextColor = Color.White,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    },
};
```

ShapeType can be

```
public enum ShapeType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A 4-sides shape (square/rectangle) - can have rounded corners
        /// </summary>
        Box,
        /// <summary>
        /// A circle shape with a radius equals to the minimum value between height &amp; width
        /// </summary>
        Circle,
        /// <summary>
        /// A star shape for which you can define the number of points and the radius ratio
        /// </summary>
        Star,
        /// <summary>
        /// A triangle shape - the appearance depends on the height/width ratio
        /// </summary>
        Triangle,
        /// <summary>
        /// An oval shape - the appearance depends on the height/width ratio
        /// </summary>
        Oval,
        /// <summary>
        /// A diamond shape - 4-sides - the same you can find in a card deck - the appearance depends on the height/width ratio
        /// </summary>
        Diamond,
        /// <summary>
        /// A heart shape - the appearance depends on the minimum value between height &amp; width
        /// </summary>
        Heart,
        /// <summary>
        /// A progress circle shape acting like a progress bar with a radius equals to the minimum value between height &amp; width
        /// </summary>
        ProgressCircle,
        /// <summary>
        /// A custom path shape defined by a list of points
        /// </summary>
        Path
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Snip from my xamarin proj

### Working example:

```
<Frame
    CornerRadius="15"
    Padding="0"
    BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite"
    Margin="15,10,15,10" 
    HasShadow="False"
>
    <Label Margin="5" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
        Text="My rounded label" />
</Frame>
```

Things to note are CornerRadius of the frame and the margin and transparent background of the label itself. The width of the 'label' could be set as it is here or managed with the container of your choice. I did not want to complicate the answer with more code.

HTH